# SaveField Cakephp validation

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have this problem.. i can't validate 2 fields of my form and use SaveField for save the data but can't validate.. check the code:

Archivo.php (Model)

```
<?php
class Archivo extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Archivos';

    public $validate = array(
        'mes' => array(
            'rule' => 
                array('multiple', array(
                    'min' => 1
                )
            ),
            'message' => 'Debe Seleccionar Una (1) Opción',
            'required'  => true,

        ),

        'ano' => array(
            'rule' => 
                array('multiple', array(
                    'min' => 1
                )
            ),
            'message' => 'Debe Seleccionar Una (1) Opción',
            'required'  => true,

        ),

    );
}

?>
```

ArchivosController

```
<?php
class ArchivosController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'Archivos';
    var $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    //var $scaffold;

.
.
.

    function add(){ ###FORMULARIO PARA SUBIR ARCHIVOS DE TEXTO AL SISTEMA

        $this->Archivo->create();
        #### SI LA INFORMACION ENVIADA ES 'POST' SE PROCEDE A TRABAJAR CON EL ARCHIVO SINO CREARA UN FORMULARIO EN BLANCO
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {                
            debug($this->request->data);
            ##### DEL POST SE VERIFICA SI EL ARCHIVO TIENE ALGUN FALLO O SI NO TIENE NADA 
            if( $this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['error'] == 0 &&  $this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['size'] > 0){
                // Informacion del tipo de archivo subido $this->data['Upload']['archivo']['type']
                ####DONDE SE GUARDARAN LOS ARCHIVOS SUBIDOS
                $destino = WWW_ROOT.'files'.DS;
                ##### MOVEMOS EL ARCHIVO DE LA CARPETA TEMPORAL A LA RUTA SELECCIONADA ($DESTINO),
                ##### EN BASE DE DATOS SOLO SE GUARDARA LA RUTA, EL MES Y EL AÑO DEL ARCHIVO
                if(move_uploaded_file($this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['tmp_name'], $destino.$this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['name'])){
                    $this->Archivo->saveField('ruta', $destino.$this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['name']); 
                    $this->Archivo->saveField('mes', $this->data['Archivo']['mes'], true);
                    $this->Archivo->saveField('ano', $this->data['Archivo']['ano']['year'], true);              
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Archivo Guardado'));
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('El archivo no se pudo subir, por favor intentelo de nuevo'));       
                }
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error al intentar subir el archivo'));
            }
        }    
    }  
}

?>
```

add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Archivo', array('type' => 'file'));?>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Añadir Nuevo Archivo</legend>
    <?php 
    //echo $this->Form->input('mes',array('type'=>'date'));
    echo $this->Form->input('mes', array(
        'options'=>array(
            'Enero'=>'Enero',
            'Febrero'=>'Febrero',
            'Marzo'=>'Marzo',
            'Abril'=>'Abril',
            'Junio'=>'Junio',
            'Agosto'=>'Agosto',
            'Septiembre'=>'Septiembre',
            'Octubre'=>'Octubre',
            'Noviembre'=>'Noviembre',
            'Diciembre'=>'Diciembre'),
        'empty'=>'(Seleccione un Mes)',
        'label'=>'Mes'
        )
    );
    //echo $this->Form->year('ano','2013',date('Y'),array('empty'=>'(Seleccione un Año)','label' =>'Año'));
    echo $this->Form->input('ano', array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'dateFormat' => 'Y',
        'minYear' => date('Y'),
        'maxYear' => date('Y') + 1,
        'label' => 'Año',
        'empty' => '(Seleccione un Año)',
        //'default' => date('Y')
    ));


    echo $this->Form->input('archivo',array('type' => 'file','label'=>''));
    //echo $this->Form->input('valido', array('checked'=>'true'));
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Enviar') ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Mostrar Todos Los Archivos',array('action'=>'index')); ?>
```

the fields cant validate are 'mes' and 'ano' and save the data

$this->Archivo->saveField('mes', $this->data['Archivo']['mes'], true);
$this->Archivo->saveField('ano', $this->data['Archivo']['ano']['year'], true);

i tried putting the code like this

$this->Archivo->saveField('ano', $this->data['Archivo']['ano']['year'], array('validate' => true));

but doesnt work

please help, thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `saveField` 3 times instead of calling `save` once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this instead:

```
$this->data['Archivo']['ruta'] = $destino . $this->data['Archivo']['archivo'];
if(move_uploaded_file($this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['tmp_name'], $destino.$this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['name']) && $this->Archivo->save($this->data)){ 
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Archivo Guardado'));
}
```

It should work better - I don't think automagic validation works with `saveField()`. And as another user pointed out, there's no point in using `saveField` many times when you can just call `save` once.

Buena suerte!

Comment: i change the code to:

<code> 
if(move_uploaded_file($this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['tmp_name'], $destino.$this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['name'])){ 
     $this->request->data['Archivo']['ano'] = $this->data['Archivo']['ano']['year'];
     $this->request->data['Archivo']['ruta'] = $destino . $this->data['Archivo']['archivo']['name'];
     $this->Archivo->save($this->request->data);
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Archivo Guardado'));
    }  
</code>

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up with your array indices. Why is it `['Archivo']['archivo']['tmp_name']` and `['Archivo']['ano']`? I think it should only be 2 levels for everything.

Comment: I change the code with Archivo->save (and works)... but can't validate anyway... in the view seems validate because appears the (*) of required but when i click the button to save the form the validation omitted @SharkofMirkwood

Answer (score 1):

saveField sets validation to false

Comment: but the validation can be sets true (documentation say that), but its doesnt work